# Make Gson create empty lists rather than nulls during de-serialization

Tags: java, gson

I want gson to de-serialize JSON arrays like

```
{
    "list" : []
}
```

to a Java Object where `model.list` is an empty `List` rather than `null`.

What should I pass to the `GsonBuilder` to get the de-serializing behavior I want.

Comment: What's the class you are trying to serialize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Gson 2.3.1 and the default behavior is ok

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.List;

public class GsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"list\":[]}";
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Pojo pojo = g.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(pojo.list.size());
        System.out.println(pojo);
    }
}

@ToString
class Pojo {
    List<Object> list;
}
```

and I got

```
0
Pojo(list=[])
```

Comment: Following the edit of the question, you might actually have understood the OP's intent